# NuGet API: ajax query returns parsererror or origin error

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, api, nuget

*Note: This is a question regarding NuGet API and directions on how to use it more than general ajax call recommendations.*

Using ajax to call the NuGet API with url like:

```
http://api.nuget.org/v3/registration1/<mypackagename>/index.json
```

Code:

```
var url = 'http://api.nuget.org/v3/registration1/{package}/index.json';
url = url.replace("{package}", NUGET_PACKAGE).toLowerCase();
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    success: function (data) {
        console.dir(data);
    },
    error: function (xhr, options, error) {
        console.dir(xhr);
    }
});
```

This always goes into the error callback, with error message

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.nuget.org/v3/registration1/cinteros.xrm.fetchxmlbuilder/index.json.
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Adding parameters to the call:
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
Now I get the parsererror with message

> Unexpected token :

Calling e.g. the Newtonsoft.Json package info directly in the browser gives a valid result.
http://api.nuget.org/v3/registration1/newtonsoft.json/index.json

How should the ajax call be composed to get a valid JSON object to work with?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I updated the text to highlight that the question really is about the NuGet API and how to use it.

Comment: The issue is the same though; their domain does not support CORS or return JSONP, therefore you cannot use JS code to make requests to it.

Comment: The cause of the problem may be the same - so I still get back to: How is NuGet API intended to be used if this approach does not work? I could have asked just that, but I wanted to supply background as well.

Comment: It can be used in any manner that can make cross domain requests, so pretty much anything bar JS.